# Scanf with space in C

Tags: c, input, struct, scanf, space

I have this structure:

```
struct bye {
    char b;
    char y;
    char e;
}
```

and I want to read with `scanf` a line that contains a word of 3 letters but between each other, there is the same unknown number of space.

For example:
"b[n number of space]y[n number of space]e" and then put in:

```
struct bye word;
```

`word.b = 'b'` `word.y = 'y'` and `word.e = 'e'`

I did something like this but it doesn't work:

```
typedef struct bye bye_s; 

bye_s setInput() {
    bye_s ret;
    char current_char;

    scanf("%c", &current_char);
    ret.b = current_char;

    do {
        scanf("%c", &current_char);
    } while (current_char == ' ');
    ret.y = current_char;

    do {
        scanf("%c", &current_char);
    } while (current_char == ' ');
    ret.e = current_char;

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: When I only use `' '` characters as the whitespace, it works for me.  If I mix in `'\t'` or `'\n'` your code doesn't handle those---for the obvious reason that you're comparing against a literal `' '`.(Maybe see `isspace` in ctype.h)  .  As stated in the answers below, the standard libraries probably have a way to get the behavior you want.  If the suggested answers don't work for your issue, you should edit the question to show the input you're supplying, and what you're getting that is surprising (vs. what you expected).

Answer (score 4):

Just use

```
if (scanf("%c %c %c", &ret.b, &ret.y, &ret.e) != 3) {
   /* failed */
}
```

Any white-space in a scanf format means to skip any amount of white space in the input.

And never forget to check the `scanf` return value!

Comment: On a 2nd call to `setInput()` this format causes trouble.  Suggest adding a space: `"%c %c %c"` --> `" %c %c %c"`.

Comment: @chux Good point. If the newline (or other ws) isn't consumed elsewhere, that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a single space in the format string, that skips an unlimited number of blank space: `scanf("%c %c %c",&char1,&char2,&char3);`